# JSON and JavaScript integration when formatting a SPARQL query in HTML

Tags: javascript, json, sparql

I have an HTML + SPARQL + JSON + JavaScript program that works correctly, shown here: http://ontomatica.com/public/test/clavius.html

Here is the SPARQL + JSON + JavaScript code:

```
function retrieveData() {
  var query = "PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> SELECT ?person ?b_date ?d_date ?abstract ?thumbnail WHERE { ?person rdf:type dbp:Person ; dbp:birthDate ?b_date ; dbp:deathDate ?d_date ; dbp:abstract ?abstract . OPTIONAL { ?person dbp:thumbnail ?thumbnail } FILTER ( ?b_date >= '1488-01-01'^^xsd:date && ?b_date < '1600-01-01'^^xsd:date && ?d_date < '1650-01-01'^^xsd:date ) FILTER ( langMatches(lang(?abstract), 'EN')) } ORDER BY ?person ?b_date";

  var url = 'http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '&output=json';

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      $('#results').show();
      $('#raw_output').text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 3));
      handle_json(data);
    },
    error: function(e) {}
  });
}

function handle_json(json) {
  $('#output_div').text("");

  $.each(
    json['results']['bindings'], function(index, value) {
      var html = "";
      name = value['person']['value'].replace("http://dbpedia.org/resource/", "");
      name = decodeURIComponent(name.replace(/_/g, " "));
      html += "<div><h3><b>" + name + ":</b> (" + value['b_date']['value'] + " - " + value['d_date']['value'] + ")</h3></div>";

      if (value['thumbnail'] != null)
        html += "<div class='inline thumb'><img style='width: 200px' src='" + value['thumbnail']['value'].replace("200px", "150px") + "'/></div>";
      else
        html += "<div class='inline thumb'><img src=''/></div>";

      html += "<div class='inline abstract'>" + value['abstract']['value'] + "</div><div class='clear'></div><br>";

      $('#output_div').append(html);
    }
  );
}
```

However, a new version of the program does not work correctly. Here are the components.

The modified SPARQL query works correctly:

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>SELECT ?food ?abstract ?thumbnail ?caption WHERE { ?food rdf:type dbp:Food ; dbpprop:name ?name ; dbpprop:caption ?caption ; dbp:abstract ?abstract . OPTIONAL { ?food dbp:thumbnail ?thumbnail } FILTER ( regex(?name, "Calzone" )) FILTER ( langMatches(lang(?abstract), "EN"))} ORDER BY ?food
```

I've tested the query on the DBpedia Virtuoso SPARQL end point. Here is the result:

```
http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3EPREFIX+dbp%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3EPREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3EPREFIX+dbpprop%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3ESELECT+%3Ffood+%3Fabstract+%3Fthumbnail+%3Fcaption+WHERE+{+%3Ffood+rdf%3Atype+dbp%3AFood+%3B+dbpprop%3Aname+%3Fname+%3B+dbpprop%3Acaption+%3Fcaption+%3B+dbp%3Aabstract+%3Fabstract+.+OPTIONAL+{+%3Ffood+dbp%3Athumbnail+%3Fthumbnail+}+FILTER+%28+regex%28%3Fname%2C+%22Calzone%22+%29%29+FILTER+%28+langMatches%28lang%28%3Fabstract%29%2C+%22EN%22%29%29}+ORDER+BY+%3Ffood&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on
```

So far, so good.

Here is the modified JSON + JavaScript program (with the operational SPARQL query).

```
function retrieveData() {
  var query = "PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>SELECT ?food ?abstract ?thumbnail ?caption WHERE { ?food rdf:type dbp:Food ; dbpprop:name ?name ; dbpprop:caption ?caption ; dbp:abstract ?abstract . OPTIONAL { ?food dbp:thumbnail ?thumbnail } FILTER ( regex(?name, "Calzone" )) FILTER ( langMatches(lang(?abstract), "EN"))} ORDER BY ?food";

  var url = 'http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '&output=json';

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      $('#results').show();
      $('#raw_output').text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 3));
      handle_json(data);
    },
    error: function(e) {}
  });
}

function handle_json(json) {
  $('#output_div').text("");

  $.each(
    json['results']['bindings'], function(index, value) {
      var html = "";
      name = value['food']['value'].replace("http://dbpedia.org/resource/", "");
      name = decodeURIComponent(name.replace(/_/g, " "));
      html += "<div><h3><b>" + name + ":</b> (" + value['caption']['value'] + ")</h3></div>";

      if (value['thumbnail'] != null)
        html += "<div class='inline thumb'><img style='width: 200px' src='" + value['thumbnail']['value'].replace("200px", "150px") + "'/></div>";
      else
        html += "<div class='inline thumb'><img src=''/></div>";

      html += "<div class='inline abstract'>" + value['abstract']['value'] + "</div><div class='clear'></div><br>";

      $('#output_div').append(html);
    }
  );
}
```

Here are the differences between the correct program and the incorrect program.

1. The DBpedia ontology term is changed from `'person'` to `'food'`.
2. The query field to be formatted in HTML output (encoded by `<div><h3></div></h3>`) is changed from `['b_date']` to  `['caption']`.

I suspect the problem is local to the `$.ajax` clause and the `JSON.stringify` statement:

```
$('#raw_output').text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 3));
```

Bottom line: I would like to generalize the first program for other applications, but am fumbling the JSON statements.

- Why does the second program fail when it is based on the first program? What am I doing wrong?
- Is there a better way to generalized the program (1) for other SPARQL queries with different terms; (2) with different numbers of terms; (3) for a SPARQL query of federated databases (only DBpedia is used in the example, but I'd like to format terms from a federated query - mashing up data from different RDF triplestores).

  - [Working Example](http://ontomatica.com/public/test/clavius.html)
  - [Non-working Example](http://ontomatica.com/public/test/calzone.html)

Comment: You might want to check out templating, for example http://handlebarsjs.com/ but there are a lot of other libraries out there

Comment: @Joshua Correct: both SPARQL queries work as intended. Apologize for flattening the SPARQL structure. Correct: query 1 binds ?person ?date ?caption. Query 2 binds ?food ?caption. In the examples, JSON is extracted & returned in $.ajax function. I am considering doing this in 3 separate steps to debug: (1) SPARQL; (2) format JSON; (3) function handle_json(json). IMHO, my error is local to this statement: $('#raw_output').text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 3));. I don't grok the JSON.stringify and believe the error is there. The URL at top works; am trying to repurpose it in ex. #2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've got unescaped quotes in the second query, which means that the Javascript engine sees a syntax error (an unexpected identifier).  The relevant part is in:

```
var query = "…FILTER ( regex(?name, "Calzone" )) FILTER ( langMatches(lang(?abstract), "EN"))} ORDER BY ?food";
```

Notice in the syntax highlighting that the string ends at the " immediately before Calzone, etc.
I found this by looking at the Javascript console in Google Chrome when loading your second sample page:

[image: error console]

You can fix this by doing:

```
var query = "…FILTER ( regex(?name, 'Calzone' )) FILTER ( langMatches(lang(?abstract), 'EN'))} ORDER BY ?food";
```

Once you've done that, you get the kinds of results you'd expect:

[image]

Comment: TY. It's better to know where to find experts than trying to be one. Also TY for showing how to find the error (for when it happens again). I went over the code character by character and missed the unescaped quote. We need more tools like this to make SPARQL relevant to end users.

Comment: @JayGray Even though I showed the Chrome console confirming the problem, I actually noticed it first when I had the code open in an editor and the syntax highlighting quickly showed the issue with the strings.  If you're not using a editor with support for syntax highlighting, I'd strongly suggest considering one!